# Flutter: how to share image via social network using image from an url

Tags: flutter, share

in my flutter app I am displaying an image from the internet using `CachedNetworkImage`.

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

I would like now to be able to share that cached image with another app, for example instagram. How can I identify the cached image and pass it as an argument for my share function. See below my code where you see my share function using `WcFlutterShare` which takes a `ByteData` as source. I would like to replace assets/images/logo.png with the cachedImage

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/logo.png');
    await WcFlutterShare.share(
        sharePopupTitle: 'share',
        fileName: 'share.png',
        mimeType: 'image/png',
        bytesOfFile: bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
  },
  child: Text(
    "Share ",
  ),
)
```

Note my current solution is as follow but I am downloading the image 2 times...

```
http.Response response = await http.get("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
final bytes = response.bodyBytes;

await WcFlutterShare.share(
sharePopupTitle: 'share',
fileName: 'share.jpeg',
mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
bytesOfFile: bytes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your own `cacheManager` to CachedNetworkImage which will allow you to retrive cached file using `getFile` [(docs)](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_cache_manager/latest/flutter_cache_manager/BaseCacheManager-class.html). Then you can retrieve the byte stream.

```
final BaseCacheManager baseCacheManager = DefaultCacheManager();

...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  baseCacheManager
      .getFile("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150")
      .listen((info) {
    log(info.file.path);
    log(info.originalUrl);
  });

  return CachedNetworkImage(
    cacheManager: baseCacheManager,
    imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
  );
}
```

This is a button I made to test my idea:

```
FlatButton(
  child: Text("Share"),
  onPressed: () {
    baseCacheManager
        .getFile("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150")
        .first
        .then((info) {
          info.file.readAsBytes().then((bytes) {
            WcFlutterShare.share(
              sharePopupTitle: 'share',
              fileName: 'share.jpeg',
              mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
              bytesOfFile: bytes);
            });
          });
}),
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense but I guess it download the image twice as the http request in my code, right?

Comment: When you got the image in cache, you will read it from the filesystem so you won't be downloading it second time :)